# Remove extension from URL using a rewrite without resulting in a redirect loop

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On the server, I have a file (on the filesystem) called `page.html`, which I want to be accessed as `site.com/page`  So if someone goes to `site.com/page.html`, it should `301` redirect to `site.com/page`

I've seen rewrite rules that will handle rewriting `/page` -> `/page.html` internally, but forcing it to `301` redirect `/page.html` -> `/page` as well causes a redirect loop for me.

The `END` flag looks like it can be used to do what I want, but it is not yet supported.

I've also tried using `ENV` as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /page.html [L,E=END:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:END} !1
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /page [R=301,L]
```

But that results in a redirect loop as well.

Comment: As it should. I do not understand what you want- to redirect a page to a directory then the directory back to the original page does not make sense to me.

Comment: @closetnoc The question has since been clarified a bit; the OP appears to be looking for help with his rewrite rule to remove the file extension, but the current one results in a redirect loop (which is a common problem when removing extensions).

Comment: If you change your line to `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} !1` it should work for you.  mod_rewrite renames the environment variable out from under you so you have to set it with one name, and read it with another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this [same question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340785/how-to-rewrite-to-a-script-and-also-redirect-away-from-that-script-using-htacce).   To get it to work properly, you have to use environment variables:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /page.html [L,E=LOOP:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /page [R=301,L]
```

This is because mod_rewrite does multiple passes through your rules.    During the first pass, it sets the environment variable.   During the second pass, it prepends the variable with the `REDIRECT_` prefix, so you have to read it as `REDIRECT_LOOP`.

Comment: +1, this may be cleaner than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, when you use mod_rewrite in an .htaccess file or a <Directory> section, every successful RewriteRule — even an internal one — [causes the request to be restarted internally](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l), and thus the whole rewrite ruleset to be reprocessed.

Thus, what's happening is that, when the user visits `/page`, your internal RewriteRule matches and rewrites the URL to `/page.html`.  But that makes Apache restart the request processing and run your ruleset again, causing the *external* rewrite rule to match and trigger a 301 redirect back to `/page`.

A quick and dirty (but effective!) fix is to make your internal rewrite rule append a dummy parameter like `redirect=no` to the URL, and check for that parameter in the external rewrite rule.  Here's an example based on [this answer I wrote for a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812059/simple-301-redirect-with-variable-not-working-why/7816300#7816300):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Externally rewrite page.html -> page, unless query includes redirect=no:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)redirect=no(&|$) 
RewriteRule ^(page)\.html$ /$1  [NS,R=301,L] 

# Internally rewrite page -> page.html, add redirect=no to query:
RewriteRule ^(page)$ $1.html?redirect=no [NS,QSA]
```

(Of course, feel free to replace `redirect=no` with something else if it conflicts with an actual URL parameter you might be using.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's the workaround that I had been using in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to prevent the redirect loop is to check against `THE_REQUEST` server variable, which contains the initial request header, rather than the URL-path of the rewritten URL (which the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against), which naturally gets updated as the URL is rewritten.

`THE_REQUEST` value does not change as the URL is *internally rewritten*, and contains a string of the form:

```
GET /page.html HTTP/1.1
```

So this could be rewritten as:

```
# Redirect direct requests for /page.html to the canonical URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(page)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Rewrite the "pretty" URL to the actual filesystem path
RewriteRule ^(page)$ $1.html [L]
```

In this case, `THE_REQUEST` condition simply makes sure that `.html` is present in the initially requested URL. The check for `page.html` is left to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - which is more efficient (since this is checked first).

It's always preferable to have any external redirects *before* the internal rewrites.