# Can certain pages load without ".html" extension, instead of whole site?

Tags: htaccess

I set up my website so that all pages load without the .html extension, using the following code in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works beautifully on the main site. The problem is that I have a few subdomains on the same site, and this change has been disastrous for those pages, with files and folders loading in ways they shouldn't.

Is it possible to do either of the following?:

a) Set up the above code to only target specific pages? This would be preferable, I think, if it's possible to do. Only 9 pages in the main site need load without the .html extension. So for example, maybe one of those "RewriteCond"s could be:

```
RewriteCond services.html -f
```

(And I have no idea if that's correct code - it's just an example of one page that needs to load without the .html extension.)

b) Alternately, could the above .htaccess code be rewritten to ADD the .html extension back in? Maybe I could add that to the subdomains' individual .htaccess files, and hopefully it would "overwrite" the main .htaccess code.

Hope someone who is more fluent at .htaccess than I am has some ideas! Thanks in advance.

Jen

EDIT: Solution found!
Thanks to some new terms given in the comments (especially mod_rewrite), I did more searching and found that the following code works to enable non-.html links:

```
RewriteRule ^page$ /page.html [L,E=END:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:END} !1
RewriteRule ^page.html$ /page [R=301,L]
```

The above code enables links to work without the .html extension. The only catch is that links that have the .html extension will still load WITH the extension (it's not removed automatically) but that's a minor issue to me. I just wanted to be able to use nicer-looking links.

Credit to my commenter Stephen, who actually solved this question years ago at: [Remove extension from URL using a rewrite without resulting in a redirect loop](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68577/remove-extension-from-url-using-a-rewrite-without-resulting-in-a-redirect-loop)

Comment: Two generic comments, but first you did not specific where these rules appear and how they apply to all your sites. In general: 1) it is far easier to have RewriteRules in the main apache configuration files, instead of in `.htaccess` files for security, performance and simplicity reasons, and 2) for very simple needs, and specially because you are saying you need the feature for only 9 pages, look at simpler stuff like `mod_alias` and its `Redirect` directives. I also suggest not matching `THE_REQUEST` as this is far too much for the simple needs you have...

Comment: You may also wish to expand on "this change has been disastrous for those pages, with files and folders loading in ways they shouldn't. " What does that mean exactly? What did you test? What URLs did you use? What was the result? What did you expected instead? and so on...

Comment: Thank you, Patrick. I will search for info on mod_alias and Redirect. I used htaccess because that's more familiar - I have never worked with apache config. Sorry for not being clearer on the subdomain issues. Example: one of the subdomains has a directory called "photos" and a page that sits alongside called "photos.html." With the code above, a browser request for the photo.html page returned a page listing the "photos" directory files instead. Since the subdomain has many setups like that, the problem needs fixing.

Comment: "a browser request for the photo.html page returned a page listing the "photos" directory files instead." This is because of your last 2 lines: you are saying "if anything ends in .html, just strip it, and 301 redirect to new URL", so yes "photos.html" is rewritten to just "photos" and then Apache detects it is a directory and `mod_autoindex` or equivalent jumps in. Anyway, make sure to have your `.htaccess` file in the specific subdirectory of the virtual host you want it to apply, and not for all virtual hosts. And I recommend reworking your last 2 lines of configuration.

Comment: The problem is that the .htaccess file for the main site also controls the subdomains. The subdomains have their own .htaccess files, but those would have to have code that adds the .html back in again (the "idea b" that I gave above). Yes, this is not an ideal setup but right now I just need to make it work as it is. I'll look into the RewriteRules idea that you originally gave. I only used the .htaccess method because that was the answer given in every search I did for "how to strip .html extension from URL."

Comment: Why don't you just move the subdomains to a different document root and change your virtual hosts?  That way they won't share .htaccess rules with your main domain.

Comment: Stephen, thanks to additional searches based on Patrick's terminology, I was able to find the perfect code in an answer you gave years ago! See above. Thanks!

Comment: "EDIT: Solution found!" - Please add your "solution" as an _answer_ below - which you can later "accept". Currently, this question is still officially "unanswered" and consequently  appears in the unanswered question queue.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek "look at simpler stuff like `mod_alias` and its `Redirect` directives" - mod_alias is no use here because the OP is primarily wanting to internally rewrite the URL (the external redirect is secondary and must then be done with mod_rewrite to avoid a redirect loop). "I also suggest not matching `THE_REQUEST` ..." - This is a perfectly valid, and necessary, way to prevent a redirect-loop in this situation.

Comment: @MrWhite "look at" means "look at" not necessarily "it is better/solves your problem with". A lot of `mod_rewrite` use cases can be handled by  `mod_alias`. So it is worth looking at. Just giving that as an **hint** based on experience. As for `THE_REQUEST` please explain why matching the HTTP version or verb matters, and why `REQUEST_FILENAME` or `REQUEST_URI` couldn't be enough...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek `THE_REQUEST` contains the initial URL of the request and, importantly, does not change when the request is rewritten. `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI` are both updated as the request is rewritten (by the earlier rewrite), so the redirect would be based on the rewritten request and not the initially requested URL (which is the intention). This would result in a redirect loop in this scenario (rewrite, redirect, rewrite, redirect, etc.). Matching the "HTTP version" and/or verb do not matter - it's just that those items are part of `THE_REQUEST`.

Comment: @MrWhite Which earlier rewrite? There is an `L` flag in the previous one. Also the documentation at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule only says that `REQUEST_FILENAME` will be updated by rewrites, it says nothing about `REQUEST_URI`. Any source?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The `L` flag simply stops the current pass through the rewrite engine - it doesn't stop all processing. The rewriting process then effectively starts over (unless a 3xx HTTP status had been set, ie. an external redirect). On the 2nd pass, the first directive (the rewrite) would not be successful, but the 2nd directive could be. (Strictly speaking, these directives should be reversed - although it doesn't make any real difference in this limited example.) You can experiment with the `END` flag instead (Apache 2.4+), although even this doesn't quite work as expected.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek The docs may not be particularly clear in this regard, however, it does state "the value of both variables will be updated". This refers to `REQUEST_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_URI` (`SCRIPT_FILENAME` is the _same as_ `REQUEST_FILENAME`). However, it's not just these variables that are updated. The URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ is also updated.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I have a few subdomains on the same site, and this change has been disastrous for those pages...
>   :
>   The problem is that the .htaccess file for the main site also controls the subdomains. The subdomains have their own .htaccess files

By the sounds of it, your subdomains map to subdirectories off the main domain's document root. In this case, you can simply enable (or disable) the rewrite engine in the subdomains `.htaccess` file in order to prevent the mod_rewrite directives in the parent config being inherited (ie. executed). (mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default.)

For example, in the subdomains `.htaccess` file:

```
# Disable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine Off
```

Alternatively, change the document root of the subdomains to point to a different area of the filesystem (as @Stephen suggested in comments) - so the main domains `.htaccess` file is not processed.